# replace same value in multiple objects

Tags: javascript

So this is been giving me a headache for quite a while:

```
{
  "gravetender": {
    "musicTokens": 2
  },
  "Bob-chan": {
    "musicTokens": 3
  }
}
```

I simply want to set all the `musicTokens` to 5, no matter the name. I've tried `forEach` and `for in`.
This is what changes the `musicTokens` for a single user for now:

```
client.profiles [message.author.username].musicTokens = 5;
```

My `client.profiles` is my JSON, the `message.author.username` gets the name and `.musicTokens` targets the variable.

I'm looking for something like `client.profiles.*.musicTokens = 5`

thanks

Comment: There is no JSON in your code.

Comment: awh so I don't know much about the code I wrote there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const client = {
  "profiles": {
    "gravetender": {
      "musicTokens": 2
    },
    "Bob-chan": {
      "musicTokens": 3
    }
  }
}

Object.values(client.profiles).forEach(profile => {
  profile.musicTokens = 5
})

console.log(client.profiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(const profile of Object.values(client.profiles))
    profile.musicTokens = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a javascript way to do this outside of a potential 3rd party plugin. You'll have to loop over them all like so

### Assuming client is a js object

```
let userNames = Object.keys(client.profiles);
usernames.forEach(username => {
    client.profiles[username].musicTokens = 5;
});
```

You can use the `Map` class to iterate over them in place

### Assuming client.profiles is Map object

```
client.profiles.forEach(profile => profile.musicTokens = 5);
```

### Make client.profiles a Map from a js object

```
client.profiles = new Map(Object.entries(client.profiles));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Comment: `You can use the Map class to iterate over them in place` i wanna see that.